# RunDec package produces error when loaded

Tags: warning-messages, packages

Has anyone used RunDec, a Mathematica package for dealing with the running of the strong coupling in particle physics? I found the source code online. When I copied and pasted its text into a .m file and attempt to load it via << RunDec.m as instructed in the relevant paper, it tells me there is a source code error on line 902 of the source code.

> Syntax::sntx: Invalid syntax in or before ",numprec]tmp}," (line 902 of "RunDec.m").

The source code is here https://www.ttp.kit.edu/Progdata/ttp00/ttp00-05/RunDec.m

Apologies for the brevity of this question, but there is no forum for RunDec online. This forum seems to be the most appropriate one to ask my question. Has anyone managed to load RunDec and use it successively?

Comment: A quick text search couldn't find the expression from your reported error in the code you linked to. You will first need to narrow this down a bit on your own. I doubt that many people will sift through the whole package code to pinpoint the error for you otherwise.

Comment: @MarcoB oh woops I thought saying line 902 was enough but indeed it appears not. I copied and pasted the source code into an emacs terminal , would you suggest I try something else? I could show the line from the code but without its surrounding content it's maybe not so helpful.

Comment: It loads for me without problems.  Don't copy and paste the code in a new `.m` file because it is already a `.m` file.  Just download it, and load it with `<< ".../RunDec.m"`  (where `...` is the directory path where you saved the file.)

Comment: @QuantumDot Thanks! But do you know the syntax to specify the directory path on a Mac? I tried << "myname/Downloads/RunDec.m" but this didn't work.

Comment: Ha! you're a noob just as I was a few years ago  ;)  .  While holding down the option key, drag the downloaded `.m` file into the Mathematica notebook.  The full path should show up as a string.

Comment: Ok thanks :) but what happens after loading << ".../RunDec.m"?  Usually I see some script but nothing happened

Comment: It defines some functions.  If you type ``?RunDec`*``, you can see the functions that are available.  I've never used this package before, so I don't know how to use those functions.  You can contact the people who wrote the package.

Comment: Ok it worked thanks very much!